# Find the value of sum_(i=0)^infinity (a^i (2 b-1) (b/(1-b))^i)/(b-1)

Tags: convergence-divergence

For an application I'm working on, I need to know the value of the following expression:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty$ $a^i  (2 b-1)\frac{(\frac{b}{(1-b)})^i}{(b-1)} $

(sorry it's not texed). According to WolframAlpha, it converges for |a| < |1/b - 1|, but WA does not give me what it converges to. Does anyone know? (It can probably be found easily with Mathematica)

Comment: I would start with simplifying that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $N\geq 0$, $$
\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{a^i (2 b-1) \left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right)^i}{b-1}
=\frac{2 b-1}{b-1}\sum_{i=0}^N a^i \left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right)^i
=\frac{2 b-1}{b-1}\sum_{i=0}^N r^i
$$
for $r\stackrel{\rm def}{=} a \left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right)$. It will (be defined and) converge when both (i) $b\neq 1$ and (ii) $\left \lvert a \left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right) \right\rvert < 1$, and then the sum will be
$$
 \frac{2 b-1}{b-1}\cdot \frac{1}{1-r} = \frac{2 b-1}{b-1} \frac{1}{1-a \left(\frac{b}{1-b}\right)}
= \frac{2 b-1}{b-1+a b}.
$$
from the formula of a geometric series.